# Python - expected string not list

Tags: python

When running the code below, I got the error message saying 'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list'

I used Spyder to debug the above error message - but I could not find the bug.
Could someone please tell me how to solve this error? The code is given below

Thank you!

```
J1 = ['520A','520B']
J2 = ['560S','580A']

JOINTS = J1 + J2

FILES_IN = ['dynres-x-eqk.lst','dynres-y-eqk.lst','dynres-z-eqk.lst'] 
FILE_OUT = ['_Accelerations.txt']

def joint_acc(joint, file_in):
    output = []
    with open(file_in, 'rt') as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            if 'JOINT ACCELERATIONS' in line:
                for line in f_in:
                    if line.startswith(joint):
                        while line.strip() != '':
                            output.append(line)
                            line = next(f_in)
                        break
    return ''.join(output)

with open(FILE_OUT, 'wt') as f_out:
    for Jt in JOINTS:
        for filename in FILES_IN:
            f_out.write(joint_acc(Jt, filename))
        f_out.write('\n')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops to show up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. Note that accepting and up-voting answers is the way to say _thanks_ on Stack Overflow. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6):

You did:

```
FILE_OUT = ['_Accelerations.txt']
```

then:

```
with open(FILE_OUT, 'wt') as f_out:
```

So this `open` get `list`, which cause `TypeError`. Try replacing `FILE_OUT = ['_Accelerations.txt']` with `FILE_OUT = '_Accelerations.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

Your `FILE_OUT` variable is `list` type but the `open` waits for `str`, `bytes` or `os.PathLike` object types.

You should convert your `FILE_OUT` variable to a correct type.

**For example to string:**

```
FILE_OUT = "_Accelerations.txt"
```

Or your can access the first element of your list with `0` index (Your list has only 1 element.)

**Like this:**

```
with open(FILE_OUT[0], 'wt') as f_out:
```